# JS: logging data

Tags: javascript

I am new to JS and ran into a problem. Here is a simple javascript snippet that wants to be used in PCIbex Farm.

It goes through asking questions from a CSV file and waits for text input for every given question. If there are at least 8 characters typed in the input, it jumps to the next sentence after pressing Enter/Return key. It logs the output data to the console, however, I want to store it in the log file and process it later.

How I can do it? If I just simply use log() then the resolve seems to be not called as I am stuck in the first question.

```
Template("Poodle-items.csv", row =>
  newTrial("experimental-trial",
    newHtml("content",
      `<div style="display: inline-block;">
        <input type="text" id="sentence" name="sentence" style="width: 200px; height: 20px;">
      </div>
      <div style="display: inline-block;">
        <p>${row.sentence}</p>
      </div>
      <div id="errorMessage"></div>`
    )
    .print(),

    newFunction(() => {
      const sentenceInput = document.getElementById("sentence");
      const errorMessage = document.getElementById("errorMessage");

      let errorMessageDisplayed = false;
      let resolveFunction;

      sentenceInput.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
        if (event.key === "Enter") {
          if (sentenceInput.value.length < 8 && !errorMessageDisplayed) {
            const errorText = document.createElement("p");
            errorText.textContent = "Please write a longer answer!";
            errorText.classList.add("errorMessage");
            errorMessage.appendChild(errorText);
            errorMessageDisplayed = true;
          } else if (sentenceInput.value.length >= 8) {
            errorMessage.innerHTML = ""; // Clear previous error message

            // Log the data
            const dataToSave = `sentence: ${sentenceInput.value}\ngroup: ${row.group}\nconjunction: ${row.conjunction}\ndegree: ${row.so}\nID: ${getVar("ID")}\n\n`;
            resolveFunction();
            console.log(dataToSave);
          }
        }
      });

      return new Promise(resolve => {
        resolveFunction = resolve;
      })
;
    })
    .call()
  )
);
```

I tried using log(), but it did not work, as I stucked at the first question (looked like log interfered with resolve). If I use console.log() I can see the data on the console, but it is not stored after the experiment is done.

Comment: _"I tried using log()"_... what exactly is `log()`? Where does it come from?

Comment: _"I want to store it in the log file"_... which log file is that? Does it already exist or do you want to create it? Is it a server-side resource or client-side?

Comment: Browser security will prevent you from writing to a local file. There are ways to store data on a client, but it's not clear that this will meet your needs. Alternatively, you can send the log data to the server (AJAX would be a good choice for this) but you need to provide an endpoint on the server to receive the data and handle it.

Comment: Thanks for replying. It is hard to answer it with my limited experience with JS. But as far as I understand .log is a function for PennController element types. So it writes to results.csv which is created automatically. But see: https://doc.pcibex.net/basic-tutorial/6_logging-data.html 
But I cannot call it within the function, but I do not have these data outside the function.